Ubuntu 24.04 - problems with iptables rules
I installed a new VM with Ubuntu 24.04. I want to secure it with iptables so I set two rules:
iptables -A INPUT -i any -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i any -j DROP

If I telnet to the VM on port 22, it's ok. If I telnet to port 8888, it resets. Why?
There is nothing listening on port 8888 so I did a nc -l -p 8888 on the VM
and then-
telnet 192.168.10.111 8888
Trying 192.168.10.111...
Connected to 192.168.10.111.
Escape character is '^]'.

What's wrong here?
I destroyed and recreated the VM to be sure of my result and I have encounter the same behavior.
Yes, ufwd is disabled and there was not rules before. It's a fresh install for this test.

Yes, ufwd is disabled and there was not rules before. It's a fresh install for this test.

Based on what you did, this is a expected behaviour, can you please point exactly at the issue you want to resolve?

Are the source and target servers installed on the same server or on your localhost?

I want to drop any connection from the external network to the host but the ssh.
The telnet commands are done from an other host

Did you check what configuration was already in place BEFORE you ran those commands?

You have to allow stateful firewall rules and select the correct interface or you will be filtering on localhost too. You have to set the default policy for the input chain to DROP. Basically, you can't learn iptables asking questions on serverfault, try this tutorial, there are examples too: https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html

We found the bug!
Ubuntu 22.04 & 24.04 are using netfilter as backend and the binary iptables is in fact iptables-nft which translate iptables rules to nft rules.
The problem here is the rule :
iptables -A INPUT -i any -j DROP

which is translated to: iifname "any" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop.
As there is no interface named any, the rule is never matched !!!
(if you change any with eth0, the rule is matched, or if you don't use the -i option).
So it's a translation bug in iptables-nft
